# user needs to check the boxes if task is completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to check the box if the task is completed and unchecked if not

I've already tried using the setstate with the e.targe.checked but it doesnt work`. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I dont want the answer but rather a detail explanation on the steps i should take. I'm new to react, please be mindful when responding . thank you in advance

```
 import React from "react"
 import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
 import todosData from "./todosData"

  class App extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        todos: todosData
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

    handleChange(id,e) {
    this.setState({
        todos: e.target.checked.id.map( (item) => {
            return todos.id
        })
      })
   }



   render() {
   const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key= {item.id} 
      item={item}
       />)

       return (
          <div className="todo-list">
            {todoItems}
          </div>
         ) 
       }   

     }

   export default App
```

// this is the todoItem component

```
     import React from "react"

     function TodoItem(props) {
      return (
      <div className="todo-item">
         <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            checked={props.item.completed} 
            onChange={props.handleChange}
          />
           <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
       )
    }

      export default TodoItem
```

Comment: Your `handleChange` implementation has a couple problems. It's going to receive an event as its first and only argument, not the ID. And I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `e.target.checked.id.map`—that would attempt to iterate the checkbox's id, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Pay closer attention to your `handleChange` function. You defined it to accept two arguments, but yet when you use it in `TodoItem` component, you do not pass in all arguments.

You can use anonymous functions to pass in values to the prop handler like so:

```
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={props.item.completed}
    onChange={e => props.handleChange(e, props.item.id)}
  />
```

The `event` object gets passed implicitly, but in order for you to pass in a 2nd argument, like the id, you need to explicitly pass the `event` object as well.

Additionally, you need to rework your `handleChange()` function a bit to locate the designated task by id. Try using the `array.prototype.find()` method to locate an item by id and then toggling the `completed` boolean value of that todo item.

The complete solution is here for your reference but try not to use it until you've given it your best shot: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-tree-hs033

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the directions, I'm new and trying to understand the logic before getting answers. Your advice helped out alot

Comment: @junior you're welcome friend! I applaud your work-ethic :)